# Angular: Problem assigning value from a promise to an external variable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am attempting to upload multiple pictures to firebase storage(from an array that stores base64 string), get the downloadURL and assign the value into another array (before uploading to cloud firestore).

```
  testuploadpic() {
    this.skillImage = this.photoService.photos; //ignore this
    for (let i = 0; i<this.skillImage.length; i++) {
      try {
        const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
        const file = this.skillImage[i];
        const filePath = `user-skill-images/${this.session.uid}_skill_${id}`;
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref(filePath);
        ref.putString(file, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpeg'}).then(function(snapshot) {
          console.log('Uploaded');
          ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            console.log(url)   //I can get the url
            this.skillImageURL[i] = url;   //Problem is at here
            console.log(this.skillImageURL);   //I get undefined
          })
        })
      } catch(e) {
        this.toastSvc.showToast(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

I have read a lot regarding to this subject, but still couldn't find a proper solution to my issue. I thank you for your time to read my problem and help.

Comment: Use arrow function

Comment: You mean `ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => { this.skillImageURL[i] = url; })` ? Still getting undefined.

Comment: try to print i before this.skillImageURL[i] = url;

Comment: it gets 0 just as I assigned to it in the for loop statement

Comment: You will need to replace both `then(function(...) {...}` with arrow functions. `function` will change the context so `this` does not relate to the surrounding class anymore (but the function body). Arrow functions keep the context.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a few typical newbies problems:

- you lost the context
- you didn't store the loop variable into the closure when working with nested async functions
- you're trying to write async API as synchronous
- you break promise chaining

Try this (not tested):

```
function testuploadpic(){
    this.skillImage = this.photoService.photos; //ignore this
    //returns array of urls
    return Promise.all(this.skillImage.map(i=>{
        const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
        const file = this.skillImage[i];
        const filePath = `user-skill-images/${this.session.uid}_skill_${id}`;
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref(filePath);
        return ref.putString(file, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpeg'}).then((snapshot)=> {
            console.log('Uploaded');
            return ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                console.log(url)   //I can get the url
                return url;   //Problem is at here
            })
        }).catch(err=>{
            this.toastSvc.showToast(err);
        })
    }));
}

testuploadpic().then(urls=> console.log(`Urls: ${urls}`));
```